# React component does not re-render reactively (Redux Observable + rxjs + rx-http-requst)

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, redux-observable

I have an API endpoint that returns a list of users in an 'application/stream+json' type response. The items are separated by a new line character.
Example data can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIrbm.png).

**Component**

```
class UserList extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const { fetchUsers } = this.props;
        fetchUsers();
    }

    render() {
        const { isFetching = false, users = [] } = this.props;
        if (isFetching) {
            return <Loader message="Users are loading..." />;
        }
        if (!users || users.length === 0) {
            return 'No users found.';
        }
        const children = users
            .map(user => <UserListItem key={user.id} user={user} />);
        return (
            <div className="UserList">
                <Paper>
                    <List>
                        <Subheader>Users</Subheader>
                        {children}
                    </List>
                </Paper>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

UserList.propTypes = {
    users: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.any),
    isFetching: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    fetchUsers: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

UserList.defaultProps = {
    users: [],
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { users, isFetching } = state.users;
    return {
        users,
        isFetching,
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        fetchUsers: bindActionCreators(actions.fetchUsers, dispatch),
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserList);
```

---

**Reducer**

```
const initialState = {
    users: [],
    isFetching: false,
};

function fetchUsers(state) {
    return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true,
    };
}

function fetchUsersItemReceived(state, action) {
    const { user } = action;
    return {
        ...state,
        users: [...state.users, user],
        isFetching: false,
    };
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.FETCH_USERS_REQUEST:
        return fetchUsers(state);
    case actionTypes.FETCH_USERS_ITEM_RECEIVED:
        return fetchUsersItemReceived(state, action);
    default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

---

**Action** (the parser is the Streaming JSON Parser found [here](https://github.com/creationix/jsonparse))

```
export function fetchUsers() {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.FETCH_USERS_REQUEST,
    };
}

function fetchUsersItemReceived(user) {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.FETCH_USERS_ITEM_RECEIVED,
        user,
    };
}


function fetchUsersSuccess() {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS,
    };
}

function fetchUsersFailure(error) {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.FETCH_USERS_FAILURE,
        error,
    };
}

function getJsonStream(url) {
    const emitter = new Subject();
    const req$ = RxHR
        .get(url)
        .flatMap(resp => resp.body)
        .subscribe(
            (data) => {
                parser.write(data);
                parser.onValue = (value) => {
                    if (!parser.key) {
                        emitter.next(value);
                    }
                };
            },
            err => emitter.error(err),
            () => emitter.complete(),
        );
    return emitter;
}

export const fetchUsersEpic = action$ =>
    action$.ofType(actionTypes.FETCH_USERS_REQUEST)
        .concatMap(() => getJsonStream(`${api.API_BASE_URL}/user`))
        .map(user => fetchUsersItemReceived(user));
```

---

**configureStore.js**

```
const logger = createLogger();

const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic);
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware, logger)(createStore);

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    return createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer, initialState);
}
```

While the list component should be refreshed after EACH item is received, it is refreshed AFTER the whole list is received. Can someone point me to the blocking point in the code?

Comment: Can you put together a working jsbin or similar? Using mock data instead of a real endpoint is fine. Has lots of moving parts (for a SO question) so hard to know without seeing running code. It's also missing how your component connects to the store

Comment: @jayphelps Added missing state flow. Will try to put a jsbin together tomorrow. I stumbled onto a possible suspect with switchMap in the epic, changed it to concatMap still no fun.

Comment: Ok feel free to ping me when it's up. FWIW switchMap vs concatMap in this example looks unrelated to the problem you're talking about as it only affects new FETCH_USERS_REQUESTs that come in while a previous one is still streaming.

Comment: @jayphelps Haven't found the time to set up a jsbin yet, although I tried streaming intervaled mock data from array and the UI re-renders correctly on every item. So the parser that converts the character stream to json objects must be blocking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with the jsonParse lib. Switching to [oboe.js](http://oboejs.com/)
fixed it. Using the "!" node selector to select multiple root JSON elements i was able to transform the character stream to a user object stream.

**Action**

```
function getJsonStream(url) {
    const emitter = new Subject();
    const emitter = new Subject();
    oboe(url)
        .node('!', (item) => {
            emitter.next(item);
        })
        .fail((error) => {
            emitter.error(error);
        });
    return emitter;
}

export const fetchUsersEpic = action$ =>
    action$.ofType(actionTypes.FETCH_USERS_REQUEST)
        .switchMap(() => getJsonStream(`${api.API_BASE_URL}/user`))
        .map(user => fetchUsersItemReceived(user));
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a solution to your particular issue (unless by accident lol) but I think a custom Observable is a better fit in this situation instead of a Subject. You can also hook into the Parser's error callback too.

Figured that others searching for streaming JSON with rxjs later might find this handy (untested)

```
function streamingJsonParse(data$) {
  return new Observable((observer) => {
    const parser = new Parser();

    parser.onError = (err) => observer.error(err);
    parser.onValue = (value) => {
      if (!parser.key) {
        observer.next(value);
      }
    };

    // return the subscription so it's correctly
    // unsubscribed for us
    return data$
      .subscribe({
        next: (data) => parser.write(data),
        error: (e) => observer.error(e),
        complete: () => observer.complete()
      });
  });
}

function getJsonStream(url) {
  return RxHR
    .get(url)
    .mergeMap(resp => streamingJsonParse(resp.body));
}
```

---

When you've had a chance to put together that jsbin let me know!